# How does sites usually get information from contracts?

Tags: nearprotocol

In smart-contract template that got created by near-create-app it's done by calling from the users wallet view functions. Hoewer, in services that's out there, like berryclub, the view methods are not called by user's wallet. Moreover, I can't find anybody calling any of view methods in the [explorer](https://explorer.near.org/accounts/berryclub.ek.near). But in [frontend code](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/qegahihiqi.apache) they're called. What kind of magic is this?

I'm asking this because I'm currently too is building a smart contract with view methods, And I'm unsure how it is supposed to be done. The simpliest would be as the deafult template showed, but I fear that that is not a right way.

Comment: Can you post an example, please?

Comment: @Doc_Failure [berryclub](https://berryclub.io)